# Преобразование списка с кортежами в одномерный список

Tags: python

Дан список:

```
b = [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,)]
```

В итоге после трансформации должны получить список формата: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Comment: Полезный ответ на английском: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Может не самый эффективный способ, но выглядит красиво:

```
>>> b = [(1,),(2,),(3,),(4,),(5,),(6,)]
>>> sum(map(list, b), []) 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> b = [(1,), (2,), (3,4), (5,)]
>>> b = [inner_elem for elem in b for inner_elem in elem]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Ещё вариант

```
from operator import itemgetter
b = [(1,),(2,),(3,),(4,),(5,),(6,)]
print(list(map(itemgetter(0),b)))
```

Вывод:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```